# Extremal set theory problem

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

What are good bounds(asymptotic bounds preferred) on the cardinality of the largest family $S$, of $m$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, if any pair of elements intersect in a set that has cardinality no larger than $k$?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
By Pigeon Hole Principle, we can have an upper bound $$ \frac{n \choose k}{m \choose k} $$; and then by Stirling's Approximation, we can obtain an asymptotic upper bound.

Comment: Have already made some change to make it more rigorous. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.@bof

Comment: A classical reference for this problem is A. E. Brouwer, "Packing and covering of $\binom kt$-sets", Mathematical Centre Tracts 106 (1979), 89-97, which starts by defining (for $0\le t\le k\le v$)$$D(t,k,v)=\min\{|\mathcal B|:\mathcal B\subset\mathcal P_k(v)\text{ and no two elements of }\mathcal B\text{ have }t\text{ points in common}\}$$where $\mathcal P_k(v)$ denotes the collection of $k$-subsets of a fixed $v$-set. Mathematical Centre Tracts 106 = *Packing and Covering in Combinatorics*, A. Schrijver, ed., Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam, 1979, ISBN 90 6196 180 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Sperner's Lemma, but Frankl-Wilson (pg 178 of jukna's extremal comb) gives an upper bound of ${n}\choose{k}$ for this problem, which seems a little steep.

Comment: Isn't $\binom nk/\binom{2k}k$ an upper bound?

Comment: If so the bound is sharp. For instance consider k=1. Then one can construct a graph with n vertices that has exactly n/2 edges with all the edges disjoint.

Comment: It's sharp for $k=1$ but that's a trivial case.

Comment: Thanks!@bof. It is indeed a good upper bound. I have used Stirling Approximation to approximate the magnitude of it. It looks just nice!